# How effectively Mathematica calculates Sum[Sum[a_k k^m, {m, 0, n}], {k, 1, p}] as a function of n?

Tags: summation, implementation-details

Suppose that I have a polynomial of order $n$
$$
f_n(k)=\sum_{m=0}^n a_k k^m,
$$
where $k$ is an integer and $a_k$ are arbitrary real numbers. Now I want to use Mathemtica to calculate
$$
\sum_{k=1}^p f_n(k).
$$
Mathematica does it pretty fast even for large $n$.

Q0. How does Mathematica calculate these sums? I'm asking mainly about how the engine processes it. I suppose it takes $k^m$ (one by one $m=0,\dots,n$) and uses some known (analytical) procedures for summing the partial sums over $k$.

Q1. What is the scaling as a function of $n$ for a fixed $p$ Mathematica achieves? Some experimenting shows that is must be polynomial in time.

Q2. Independently on Mathematica, what is the computational complexity of calculating such sums as a function of $n$ (for a fixed $p$)?

EDIT: The coefficients of $k^m$ in $f_n(k)$ are set to one but they are otherwise arbitrary real numbers so $f_n(k)$ can't be in general simplified.

EDIT: I added coefficients $a_k$ to the first sum to make the question more clear.

Comment: looking at your edit id suggest you provide a concrete example with real coefficients. That changes the question entirely..

Comment: Are you saying that Mathematica always tries to simplify the first sum before going on? I want to consider the worst-case scenario where nothing can be done to simplify the first sum.

Comment: no I was just saying the potential for analytic simplification changed the problem in a way that isn't relevant to your actual problem.  For the general problem I don't think if does anything more interesting than brute force evaluation of all `(n+1)*p` terms.

Comment: Ok, see my comment in @DumpsterDoofus's answer because this is my Q1.

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea how Mathematica evaluates such sums. However, note that $f_n(k)=\frac{k^{n+1}-1}{k-1}$, meaning that

> Q1. What is the scaling as a function of n for a fixed p Mathematica achieves? Some experimenting shows that is must be polynomial in time.

has the answer $O(1)$, provided that you force symbolic evaluation of $f_n(k)$.

Meanwhile, you could also ask what the scaling  is as a function of $p$. It's natural to guess polynomial time, which you can verify by the following:

```
Sum[k^m, {m, 0, n}]
f[p_, n_] = Sum[%, {k, 2, p}]
DiscretePlot[Log[10, #] &@First@Timing@f[Round[10^k], 12], {k, 3, 6, 0.1}]
```

[image]

The slope of the line is 1, indicating linear time, or $O(p)$ execution.

Comment: Ah, I was being sloppy and forgot to mention that the coefficients of $k^m$ were set to one just for simplicity. They can be arbitrary, please see the edit.

Comment: @user155002: In that case, no simplification is done, and it's probably just going to be $O(np)$ as george2079 said in his comment.

Comment: Ok, is it obvious that it is linear in $n$ for a fixed $p$?

Comment: @user155002: For fixed $p$, $O(np)=O(n)$, so yes. I'll edit my answer to include an example illustrating this.

Comment: I totally believe that $O(np)=O(n)$ for a fixed $p$ :) My question is does Mathematica achieve that considering the way it actually (symbolically) calculates it?

Comment: @user155002: Well, in the example you gave, there is no closed-form solution for the expression, so a symbolic evaluation in terms of variables $n$ and $p$ will not happen. That means that whenever you evaluate your expression $\sum_{k=1}^p f_n(k)$ for explicit integer values of $n,p$, it just manually adds all the $np$ terms together to get the final number, with no fancy tricks involved. Since there are $np$ terms, the operation proceeds in $O(np)$ time, and thus is linear in $n$ for fixed $p$.